# What operator '&' before a less tag means and how I can convert to scss

Tags: css, sass, less

I'm migrating an old angularJS application to angular, and I have the following `.less` code:

```
.pri-expander-list-parameters-outer {
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    div& .well {
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
}
```

What I'm not understanding what is the meaning of `&` after the `div`. Can anyone explain to me and tell me how can I convert it to `scss` or pure `css`.(maybe it is just a syntax error)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div& .well
```

this means a div container with the class well

to convert to css:

```
.pri-expander-list-parameters-outer {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.pri-expander-list-parameters-outer .well {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Missing the `div` in the CSS…!?

Comment: the div is unnecessarily because the div has the class .well

Comment: That's irrelevant. The rule may apply to different elements with or without a preceding `div` selector.